# Disable Woocommerce order completed email when order items have specific product tags

Tags: php, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, email-notifications, taxonomy-terms

I'm using the following code, but it's not working, WooCommerce is still sending emails when the order changes from processing to completed for those two product tags.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'product_tag_avoid_completed_email_notification', 10, 2 );

function product_tag_avoid_completed_email_notification( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $recipient;
    }

    // HERE set your product tags (comma-separated slugs)
    $disabled_tags = array( 'special-promo', 'regular' );

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Get the correct product ID (for variations we take the parent product ID)
        $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

        // Check for product tags for this item
        $tags = wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'product_tag' );

        // Check if any of the disabled tags are present in the product tags
        if ( array_intersect( $disabled_tags, $tags ) ) {
            return ''; // If any of the specified tags are found, we return an empty recipient
        }
    }
    
    return $recipient;
}
```

I want to disable the customer email sending when an order change from processing to completed with products tagged with " special promo" or "Regular"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes and complications in your code… Try the following simplified revised code:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'product_tag_avoid_completed_email_notification', 10, 2 );
function product_tag_avoid_completed_email_notification( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // HERE set your product tags (comma-separated term names, slugs or Ids)
        $targeted_terms    = array('special-promo', 'regular');
        $targeted_taxonomy = 'product_tag';

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Check for matching product tags 
            if ( has_term( $targeted_terms, $targeted_taxonomy, $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                return ''; // return empty recipient avoiding this email notification
            }
        }
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

[Other related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754%20woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order)